# Implementing Django Templates and jQuery Templates Together

Tags: ajax, json, django-templates, dry, jquery-templates

I'm working on a website that uses AJAX to retrieve data from the server and display it on the page. Django renders the initial page content using its template engine (so it will be indexed by search engines). When the user takes an action, jQuery fetches the new data via AJAX and the response is returned as JSON. I would like to have jQuery render this new content without violating the [DRY Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Therefore I would like to use a templating engine that is "shared" between Django and jQuery. I've been running in circles trying to find the best solution but always seem to run into a road block.

Has this already been done? Here are the options I have thought of:

- Use regular expressions to transform the Django template into correct jQuery template syntax, and render it in its raw form to the page. jQuery will then pick it up and use it to render the new data.
- Extend the jQuery template engine to recognize the Django template syntax, again rendering the raw Django template to the page for jQuery to use.

Has this been successfully done before? Either way seems like a lot of work for anything but the simplest of Django templates because of the plethora of Django tags and filters that would need accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to pick a template language that has both Javascript and Python support, and use that everywhere.

As far as I know, [Mustache](http://mustache.github.com/) is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've seen mustache before, but haven't tried to implement it since I was hoping to stick with the django template language (for now).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a *perfect* solution since I asked this question, but for the sake of development time I resorted to sending back both JSON and HTML in the AJAX response. This way the django templates still perform the HTML generation, but javascript is still free to utilize the data without having to parse the HTML.

I am sending approximately twice the data over the network, but I'm going to live with it until my application grows to the point where a smaller response is beneficial. At that point I will probably look into something like Mustache as Rob mentioned.